# Why do two fonts show text with different heights for same font-size?

Tags: html, css

Why do texts written in two different fonts with same font size appear unequal ? For example in the following code 'A' is set to 50px. In the output I see two A's with different sizes.

Can someone explain, or provide resources to understand the anatomy of texts and setting font-size, line-height etc. I couldn't find a clear explanation.

```css
body {
  font-size: 100px;
}

.one {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.two {
  font-family: "Source Serif Pro";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <span class="one">A</span>
  <span class="two">A</span>
</body>
```

Comment: Each font can have its own width and height of characters within the line-height: 1. In your case 100px.

Comment: This explains it https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/what-does-the-size-of-the-font-translate-to-exactly

Answer (score 2):

> In the days of metal type, the size of the glyphs in any particular
>   point size was determined by fitting the tallest ascender and the
>   deepest descender in the entire character set of that particular font
>   onto the metal type, or sort.
>
> In digital type, these physical restraints are no longer an issue, and
>   therefore the glyph size in relation to the digital bounding box, or
>   design space, are assigned by the typeface designer. For this reason,
>   type sizes and appearances can vary greatly from font to font.

https://www.creativelive.com/blog/why-do-font-sizes-vary/